# Descriptors in python for implementing perl's tie scalar operation

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I need some help with descriptors in python.  I wrote an automatic translator from perl to python (Pythonizer) and I'm trying to implement tied scalars, which is basically an object that acts as a scalar, but has FETCH and STORE operations that are called appropriately.  I'm using a dynamic class namespace 'main' to store the variable values.  I'm attempting to define `__get__` and `__set__` operations for the object, but they are not working.  Any help will be  appreciated!

```
main = type('main', tuple(), dict())

class TiedScalar(dict):    # Generated code - can't be changed
    FETCH_CALLED_v = 0
    STORE_CALLED_v = 0

    def STORE(*_args):
        _args = list(_args)
        self = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        TiedScalar.STORE_CALLED_v = TiedScalar.STORE_CALLED_v + 1
        self["value"] = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        return self.get("value")
    
    
    #TiedScalar.STORE = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(STORE, _args, _kwargs)
    
    
    def FETCH(*_args):
        _args = list(_args)
        self = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        TiedScalar.FETCH_CALLED_v = TiedScalar.FETCH_CALLED_v + 1
        return self.get("value")
    
    
    #TiedScalar.FETCH = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs)
    
    
    @classmethod
    def TIESCALAR(*_args):
        _args = list(_args)
        class_ = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        self = {"value": (_args.pop(0) if _args else None)}
        #self = perllib.bless(self, class_)
        #return perllib.add_tie_methods(self)
        return add_tie_methods(class_(self))

    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            self[k] = v
            #setattr(self, k, v)

def add_tie_methods(obj):    # This code is part of perllib and can be changed
    cls = obj.__class__
    classname = cls.__name__
    result = type(classname, (cls,), dict())
    cls.__TIE_subclass__ = result

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.FETCH()
    result.__get__ =  __get__

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        return self.STORE(value)
    result.__set__ = __set__

    obj.__class__ = result
    return obj

main.tied_scalar_v = TiedScalar.TIESCALAR(42)  # Generated code
assert main.tied_scalar_v == 42
main.tied_scalar_v = 100
assert main.tied_scalar_v == 100
print(TiedScalar.FETCH_CALLED_v)
print(TiedScalar.STORE_CALLED_v)
```

Here the 2 print statements print 1 and 0, so esp STORE is not being called, and fetch is not being called enough times based on the code.  Note that 'main' stores all of the user's variables, also the TiedScalar class is (mostly) generated from the user’s perl code.

Comment: The fact that you are never using the `obj` argument to either `__get__` or `__set__` is suspicious.

Comment: Why do you peel off `self` from the argument list manually, rather than `def fun(self, *_args):`? This looks like rather slavishly copied from how you'd do this in (legacy) Perl.

Comment: The code for FETCH, STORE, and TIESCALAR was generated by Pythonizer. I just need help with add_tie_methods

Comment: Curious: why use `*_args` for `TIESCALAR` instead of the straightforward `def TIESCALAR(cls, value=None)`? As a class method, it's always going to receive a class as an argument. (It's not entirely clear why `value` should be optional; what does `TiedScalar.TIESCALAR()` do?)

Comment: Again TIESCALAR is generated by an automatic translator from Perl to Python.  Perl doesn’t have real parameters to subs, just an array is passed in with all the arguments.  Some perl code is written to do things like conditionally peel off arguments from the arglist, so.I have to translate it like this.

Comment: @chepner - I added a print statement in \__get__ and \__set__, and \__get__ is called exactly once with "({'value': 42}, None, <class '\__main__.main'>)".  \__set__ is never called and I have no idea why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - with your help, I was able to figure out how to do it.  Basically I have to create a metaclass for my `main`, then use that class to store the initial object for tied scalars.  Here is my updated code with changes marked `# new`:

```
meta = type('mainmeta', (type,), {
    '__init__': lambda cls, name, bases, attrs: type.__init__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
})      # new
#main = type('main', tuple(), dict())
main = meta('main', tuple(), dict())    # new

class TiedScalar(dict):    # Generated code - can't be changed
    FETCH_CALLED_v = 0
    STORE_CALLED_v = 0

    def STORE(*_args):
        _args = list(_args)
        self = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        TiedScalar.STORE_CALLED_v = TiedScalar.STORE_CALLED_v + 1
        self["value"] = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        return self.get("value")
    
    
    #TiedScalar.STORE = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(STORE, _args, _kwargs)
    
    
    def FETCH(*_args):
        _args = list(_args)
        self = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        TiedScalar.FETCH_CALLED_v = TiedScalar.FETCH_CALLED_v + 1
        return self.get("value")
    
    
    #TiedScalar.FETCH = lambda *_args, **_kwargs: perllib.tie_call(FETCH, _args, _kwargs)
    
    
    @classmethod
    def TIESCALAR(*_args):
        _args = list(_args)
        class_ = _args.pop(0) if _args else None
        self = {"value": (_args.pop(0) if _args else None)}
        #self = perllib.bless(self, class_)
        #return perllib.add_tie_methods(self)
        return add_tie_methods(class_(self))

    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            self[k] = v
            #setattr(self, k, v)

def add_tie_methods(obj):    # This code is part of perllib and can be changed
    cls = obj.__class__
    classname = cls.__name__
    result = type(classname, (cls,), dict())
    cls.__TIE_subclass__ = result

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        #print(f'__get__({self}, {obj}, {objtype})')
        return self.FETCH()
    result.__get__ =  __get__

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        #print(f'__set__({self}, {obj}, {value})')
        return self.STORE(value)
    result.__set__ = __set__

    obj.__class__ = result
    return obj

def assign_meta(cls, var, value):       # new
    meta = cls.__class__
    setattr(meta, var, value)
    return value

# main.tied_scalar_v = TiedScalar.TIESCALAR(42)
assign_meta(main, 'tied_scalar_v', TiedScalar.TIESCALAR(42))    # new
assert main.tied_scalar_v == 42
main.tied_scalar_v = 100
assert main.tied_scalar_v == 100
print(TiedScalar.FETCH_CALLED_v)
print(TiedScalar.STORE_CALLED_v)
```

Comment: Will be implemented in next Pythonizer: https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/issues/301

Answer (score 2):

[*The OP has clarified in the comments that they only want a subset of Perl's functionality, and specifically just `main.tiedscalar`. That can be supported.*]

---

You can't achieve what you want using `__get__` and `__set__`, if at all.

---

First, let's get a taste of what's a tied scalar.

Take this sample class:

```perl
package Four;

use Carp qw( carp );

sub TIESCALAR {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless( {}, $class );
}
 
sub FETCH {
    my $self = shift;
    return 4;
}
 
sub STORE {
    my $self = shift;
    my $val  = shift;
    carp( "Ignoring uncouth value $val" ) if $val != 4;
}
```

And this program:

```perl
use Four;

tie my $scalar, Four::;

say $scalar;   # 4
$scalar = 3;   # Warns
say $scalar;   # 4
```

This means you need a mechanism that results in `print scalar` calling a function associated with `scalar` to produce the result.

But `__get__` and `__set__` can't do that. `__set__` only works for attributes of objects, and `__get__` also works for attributes of classes, but neither work for standalone variables. For example,

```py
class WithGet():
    def __get__( self, obj, objtype=None ):
        return 4

class Class():
    scalar = WithGet();

scalar = WithGet()
obj = Class()

print( Class.scalar )   # 4
print( obj.scalar )     # 4
print( scalar )         # <__main__.WithGet object at 0x7f420064ea00>
```

---

You will need to find a different approach. It's possible that none exist.

To translate a Perl program in Python accurately, you will surely have to build a `Scalar` class and work with instances of this class rather than native values.

For example, the following warns *once*:

```perl
my $x = "abc";
say 0+$x;   # Warns `Argument "abc" isn't numeric in addition (+) at -e line 1.`
say 0+$x    # No warnings
```

Comment: In my case of Pythonizer, I was only gonna support scalars that are global variables, which I represent as main.scalar_v. I do know I can’t make it work for “my” scalars, but main.scalar_v _is_ an attribute of my main class.

Comment: Then it's just `main.scalar_v = ClassWithGetAndSet()`

Comment: Ike - that’s what I’m attempting to create with add_tie_methods - not sure why it isn’t working.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following precondition:

```py
class Main:
   pass

main = Main()
```

Let's assume that you accept that

```perl
tie $main::scalar, Class::, ARGS;

$main::scalar = 123;
say $main::scalar;
```

is equivalent to

```py
Main.scalar = TiedScalar( Class, ARGS )

main.scalar = 123
print( main.scalar )
```

If so, the following is the only missing bit:

```py
class TiedScalar:
   def __init__( self, cls, *args ):
      self.obj = cls.TIESCALAR( cls, *args )
   def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
      return self.obj.FETCH( )
   def __set__( self, instance, value ):
      return self.obj.STORE( value )
```

Test/Demo:

```py
class Main:
   pass

main = Main()

class TiedScalar:
   def __init__( self, cls, *args ):
      self.obj = cls.TIESCALAR( *args )
   def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
      return self.obj.FETCH( )
   def __set__( self, instance, value ):
      return self.obj.STORE( value )

class Four:
   @classmethod
   def TIESCALAR( cls, *args ):
      return cls()
   def FETCH( self ):
      return 4
   def STORE( self, value ):
      if value != 4:
         raise Exception( "How dare you?" )

Main.scalar = TiedScalar( Four )

print( main.scalar )   # 4
main.scalar = 5        # Exception: How dare you?
```

---

Support for `UNTIE` and `DESTROY` left to the OP.

Note that this will only work for `obj.scalar`, not for `Class.scalar` or just `scalar`. But the OP indicated this is sufficient for their needs.

Comment: Thanks but how can I get it to work with my add_tie_methods implementation, as that routine is what I call to implement TIEARRAY and TIEHASH.  I want to add an if statement for TIESCALAR and add the necessary dunder routines to the class, like for TIEARRAY, I add \__getitem__ and \__setitem__ et.al.

Comment: FYI here is the current add_tie_methods - I’m trying to add support for TIESCALAR here: https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/blob/master/pyf/_add_tie_methods.py

Comment: The arguments are all wrong. You accept one argument that's an object, but tying requires a reference to a variable and a class. And as my other answer makes clear, and as reiterated by this answer, the variable must specifically be a class attribute.

Comment: Ok, but the TiedScalar class is generated from the user's Perl code (and is actually a mock-up because the class is dynamically generated), and the main.tied_scalar_v is initialized by TiedScalar.TIESCALAR(42).  These things cannot be changed.  42 is the initial value for the scalar.

Comment: I run pdb on my code - \__get__ is being called once on "assert main.tied_scalar_v == 42", but then when "main.tied_scalar_v = 100" is run, it doesn't call \__set__, it just changes the object to be an int with value 100, losing all the tie magic.

Comment: Re "*Ok, but the TiedScalar class is generated from the user's Perl code*", No. TiedScalar is an internal helper class. In my example, Four is the user-provided class.

Comment: Re "*42 is the initial value for the scalar*", What TIESCALAR does is irrelevant. Translating the user-provided TIESCALAR is outside of the scope of this question and answer.

Comment: Re "*it doesn't call `__set__`*", That's not true. `__set__` is called. What did you change? Sounds like your `main` is a class. In my code, it's an object. And I specifically said it only works if it's an object. Not only did I say this in this answer, my earlier answer explains exactly this.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what is the major thing you're doing different than I am - you have a main object - where in my case, main is a class.  I don't think I can create a main object just to support TIESCALAR, as I currently don't have a main object.  Is that the only way this will work?

Comment: Re "*Is that the only way this will work?*", See other answer. It's the only way it will work using `__get__` and `__set__`. Beyond that, I can't say

Comment: I figured it out - I used a metaclass above main to store the attribute instead of creating a main object that I don’t need - I was actually able to create the metaclass on demand only when a user uses TIESCALAR (will be in the next version of Pythonizer).